# Android-Java: Invocation of the setValue() method to store two different values on Firebase doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

I'm a newbie of programming Android apps, specially using Firebase platform. I have to store two different values into two different children of the same root node on a Firebase RealTime Database. I'm using the setValue() method but the problem is that the first invocation works, while the second one doesn't have effect. I paste the relative part of code hoping it will be useful for a better view of the environment. Did I make any mistake?

```
public Boolean store() {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("posts").push().setValue(this); //it has effect
    mDatabase.child("groups").push().setValue(this.author); //it hasn't effect
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `this.author`? Log it or step through debug to find out.

Comment: @DougStevenson it's a private variable of the class to whom the methods belongs. I've already logged it with `Log.d(TAG, this.author)` and the output is right.

Comment: Is it null? That value won't write - there are no "empty" locations in Realtime Database.  Do you have security rules set up at all?

Comment: @DougStevenson no, it's not null, the output is the value that the variable should have. The only rule which is set is that users must be authenticated to have permissions of read/write on db (and the user is correctly signed in, in fact it writes in 'posts' node but not in 'groups' one).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to make a Hashmap to push two values

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            dataMap.put("posts", this);
            dataMap.put("groups", this.author);
```

and then push it with a addOnCompleteListener

```
mDatabase.push().setValue(dataMap)
```

Comment: It could be a solution, but 'this' is an isntance of a class while 'this.author' is just a String, so maybe I'll have an error on the first 'put'.

Comment: You need to push strings to firebase